# HTML links between local pages don't correctly

Tags: html

I'm just starting to learn HTML and CSS and I'm trying to design a basic website. I've been trying to make links between different local web pages using: 
`<a href="Subpages/Our product/Contact.html">Contact Us</a>` and it works really well at first but then when I try using more links they sort of start stacking leading to a non-existent directory.

Ex:

**First Link used:**
`file:///C:/Users/Desktop/WebPage/Main/Subpages/Contact.html` but then when I use another link it makes this:

**Second link used:**
`file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Webpage/Subpages/contact/Webpage/Main.html` instead of just
`file:///C:/Users/Desktop/Webpage/main.html`

Comment: Seems like you are missing a / pointing to root of your directory structure. Try changing  href="Subpages/Our product/Contact.html" to  href="/Subpages/Our product/Contact.html" and add / in front of all other links you have in href

Comment: Thank very much! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Looks like you are using file paths from your computer's root, rather than your html project folder. When working on an html project, everything can be contained to the html project folder, including writing paths to files and subfolders within your html project folder.

Here is a basic folder structure to showcase path linking:

```
[project-folder]
↳[pages]
  ↳about.html
  ↳index.html
↳[scripts]
  ↳script.js
↳[stylesheets]
  ↳style.css
```

In the `index.html` page, if you wanted to link to the `about.html` page using an anchor tag: `<a href="about.html">To about page</a>`

Also in the `index.html` page, if you wanted to link a `stylesheet file` and a `JavaScript file`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/style.css">`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/script.js"></script>`

The `../` in the path means you exit out of the current folder (`pages`), then `scripts/` means you enter the `scripts` folder.

I would take a look at a quick [html file paths tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) to get more familiar with this topic.

Hope this helps! Keep at it! :)